# how to write mongo request using find and update

Tags: express, mongoose, async-await, request, backend

currently i have the following code :

```
const getApi = {
   method: 'GET',
   uri: https://example.com,
   headers: {
     Authorization: 
       'api_secret_key'
    }
    json: true
}
const updateObj = await rp(getApi);
updateObj.forEach(async param => {
    await DB1.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
       data_id: param.id
    }
  )
})
```

I am using older version of node how to rewrite it using request. I am using for each and findoneandupdate from external api to my db. any help i cant use this request promise on my node..

Answer (score 0):

## When async & await in loop:

Basically await is not working properly in `forEach` loop. use `map` instead of forEach.

```
updateObj.map(async param => {
    return await DB1.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
       data_id: param.id
    }
  )
})
```

To know more : [async & await in loop](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/)